# Bundle install do not work for rails-4.2.6 for bundler 2.0.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.4

RVM is set on `ruby-2.4.0` & I created new application which have version,

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.6'
```

I updated bundler using,

```
gem update --system
gem install bundler
bundle version
# Bundler version 2.0.1 (2019-01-04 commit d7ad2192f)
```

But I am getting following error while `bundle install`,

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.............
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.2.6) was resolved to 4.2.6, which depends on
      bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (2.0.1)
This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?

Could not find gem 'bundler (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0)', which is required by gem 'rails (= 4.2.6)', in any of the sources.
```

It is asking me for lower version version of bundler required, why? How should I solve above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Gemfile` specifies older bundler version which is not compatible with 2.x.x. Try to run `gem install bundler -v 1.3.0` or whatever version you have listed in your `Gemfile.lock` (check the very end of file).

Comment: Installed old version but showing 2.0.1 for `bundle --version`

Comment: okay, you probably need to remove the newer bundler first `gem uninstall bundler --version 2.0.1`

Comment: Yup, followed same and worked, easy but got difficult as never tried before! thanks:)

Comment: In `Gemfile.lock` file the bundler version was 2.0.1 for me, I changed that into `1.16.1` as my project really needed that. Do `bundle install` It works!

Answer (score 12):

Install any bundler with version (< 2.0, >= 1.3.0).

For example

```
gem install bundler -v 1.17.3
```

And then

```
bundle _1.17.3_ install
```

It should work for your situation.